# How do you slice a DF using .loc with a list which might have elements not found in index / column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, slice

I have couple of list which might have elements that are not found in the index / columns for a DataFrame. I want to get the particular rows / columns using these indices such that the if the elements in the list is not found in the index / column then it is ignored.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"x":[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
   "y":[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]}, 
   index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])

df1.loc[['c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], ['x', 'z']]
```

I want to get:

```
     x 
c  3.0
d  4.0
e  5.0
```

instead of:

```
     x   z
c  3.0 NaN
d  4.0 NaN
e  5.0 NaN
f  NaN NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `filter` function:

```
row_index = ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
col_index = ['x', 'z']

df1.filter(row_index, axis=0).filter(col_index, axis=1)
#   x
#c  3
#d  4
#e  5
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you need [`Index.intersection`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.intersection.html):

```
a = ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
b =  ['x', 'z']

print (df1.index.intersection(a))
Index(['c', 'd', 'e'], dtype='object')

print (df1.columns.intersection(b))
Index(['x'], dtype='object')

df2 = df1.loc[df1.index.intersection(a),df1.columns.intersection(b)]
print (df2)
   x
c  3
d  4
e  5
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can just drop rows and columns containing all null values.

```
>>> df1.loc[['c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], ['x', 'z']].dropna(how='all').dropna(how='all', axis=1)
   x
c  3
d  4
e  5
```